# Autocorrelation in Panel Data

Tags: r, panel, plm, random-effects

I employed a random-effects `plm` model (from package `plm`) to estimate my coefficients and I used the `vcovHC` in order to correct for heteroskedasticity.

However, how can I correct for autocorrelation as well? Should I use `vcovNW` or `vcovSCC`? because I tried with the `vcovHC Arellano` but, as it would be expected, I obtain the same results as by using only `vcovHC`.

How can I take the residuals autocorrelation into account in such a model?

Comment: did you use the `sandwich` package? you might want to clarify that in your question.

Comment: Yes I did, I used the sandwich package